# Angular - how to create a child component using Angular CLI

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

I have created an Angular app using Angular CLI and created one component:
`ng g c parent`.

How do I create child components (e.g. child1 and child2) and integrate them with a parent using angular CLI?

I am trying to create a simple example and understand in some example parent-child component relationship.

Comment: this tutorial may be helpful: https://www.tektutorialshub.com/adding-child-component-angular-2/

Comment: You can simply create a component with angular CLI. depending on your requirements you can use that component as a child component using input/output parameters. There is no out of the box 'child ' component.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can create as many as component you want

```
ng g c child1
ng g c child2
```

Then you need to add them in the Html of `ParentComponent`

```
<app-child1></app-child1>
<app-child2></app-child2>
```

and then using `@Input` and `@Output` to pass data between parent and child

Answer (score 15):

If you mean to nest the components into the parent you can do it like this

```
ng generate component parent/child1
ng generate component parent/child2
```

This generates the child components inside the parent folder. I do this in my apps to keep together what belongs together! Hope it helped

Comment: Can I create `parent1/child1` and `parent2/child1`  or `child1` must be unique every time? (even though it is under `parent1` and `parent2`)

Answer (score 1):

You can see child routing configuration y child routing component in Angular.io.

[angular.io router](https://angular.io/guide/router)